# QField on tablet wont open project

Tags: qfield

I run QField on both a tablet and my phone. In the last couple of days I suddenly can't open any of my projects on the tablet. They all work fine on my phone which is running the same version 1.6.4.  All of them share the majority of their files, which consist of a half dozen spatialite files and geopackages.

Last night I recopied several files to the tablet and opened the project I need today, but now that I am in the field it doesn't work. I've reinstalled the program as well.

To be specific this is what happens. Qfield starts normally and will open the sample projects that come bundled with it. If I select any of my projects it crashes during the project load. There are no error messages.

I cant find a log file in the ch.opengis.qfield directories. How can I find out what the problem is?

Comment: Try to look at the Android logcat. More info about logcat https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6iDw76UpQw

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find out what is causing this?

Comment: @David this was a while ago, and I'm not certain how I resolved it but I think the problem was a corrupted database on the tablet that all of my projects shared. Delete and make fresh copies of your data on the device.